# alertDialog in onItemClick

Tags: android, android-dialog, android-menu

I have an alertDialog inside my ListView's onItemClick().

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FragmentActivity.this);
       alertDialogBuilder
       .setMessage("Do you wish to save any new/updated defects?")
       .setCancelable(false)
       .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) 
           {
                saveMe();
           }
       })
       .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
               dialog.cancel();
           }
       });
       AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
       alertDialog.show();
```

This dialog box is created only after the entire `onItemClick()` is executed. This will result in the dialog box appearing after the new item in the menu is shown.
I want the dialog box to appear before the menu item is selected and shown. How can that be done?

Comment: _This dialog box is created only after the entire onItemClick() is executed._! What else could you expect.?

Comment: Actually when should your dialog appear??U have done code after an item is clicked in listview that dialog should appear..When you want that dialog to be appeared??

Comment: I want the dialog box to be created after a menu item is clicked- true.     The click will now add in new views and remove the previous views. I want the dialog box to appear while the old views are still present and only upon the click of 'yes' or 'no' of the dialog, the new view of the menu item click should be loaded.

Comment: @PramodSetlur , are you talking abt context menu? or standard/normal menu?

Comment: its a normal `MenuItem`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write this in your base adapter any component click event

Comment: This didn't help. Same result.

Comment: it's an acitivity in my class. and this is used for creating the dialog

Comment: Hmm, still a beginner. I didn't follow the jargon.

Comment: i mean that if you use any layout in list item to render then just get that view find your component put click on listener in base adapter